# How can I create a SharePoint 2013 access request approval using MS Flow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, power-automate

How would/can I use MS Flow to create an approval flow for the pending access requests list in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Flow to work with on-prem by deploying the Microsoft Data Gateway service to a server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem.

Then use flow to create an approval workflow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/modern-approvals

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I installed the gateway on the SharePoint server but the site address isn't recognized in the flow site address drop down list. I selected custom and added the site address to the box which appears to accept the information. Should the sites appear in the dropdown after setting up the gateway?  Also, I click Gateways under Data in Flow and get "Premium Account Required.  These features require an account for work or school and you have a personal email."  I'm logged in using my work email.

Comment: Sometimes, it happens. I used to meet this issue in SP Online. As long as the flow can recongnize the site url, it will be fine.  Besides, this article would be helpful to you:https://melihubb.com/2017/09/04/my-experience-with-setting-up-flow-with-an-on-prem-sharepoint-2016-environment/

Comment: Great blog.  I attempted to add a SharePoint on-prem connection (which I thought I already did but it was for the cloud) and I get "Your license doesn't support use of gateways."  I checked my O365 account and had Flow Free selected.  I unticked Flow Free and ticked Flow for Office 365 (Office 365 E3) but still get the license message.

Comment: Accodring to this thread: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/quot-Your-license-s-doesn-t-support-use-of-gateways-quot/td-p/142166. Flow Free cannot use on-premises data gateway.  Flow for Office365 could use gateways. Please clear the cache and try again.

Comment: Per Microsoft, the information in the above link is deprecated.  Updated information can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq.